# how can create specific input type on edittext? The input accettable is Roman numbers M D C X V I

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

I' ve extend edittext class, how can create a custom input type to accept just this characters (M,C,D,X,V,I)? This is my class that extend EditText

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DecimalEditText extends EditText{

    public DecimalEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    }
    public int getArabic(String roman){
        ConversioneTest ca = new ConversioneTest();
        int i = ca.convertToDecimal(roman);
        return i;

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to implement an [`InputFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to restrict the input to the acceptable characters and assign that to the `EditText`. In first iteration, this is really simple. Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/LoginFilter.java#L164) of `LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGeneric` for an example. You'll have this set up in minutes.

If that's all you need, great, stop there! Unfortunately, this may be all you need. There are some grammatical rules to roman numerals, for instance XXCI is (100-20)+1=81, but IXXC is not 100-(20-1)=81. If you want to cover that, then `InputFilter` is too crude. You'll still use the InputFilter to make the initial filtering, but you'll have to implement [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on top of that to handle the advanced input validation. The `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher` ([source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java)) gives you some clues on how to do that. It's an awful lot more work than just the `InputFilter`, because you'll have to deal with all sorts of weird multi-character inputs, such as clipboard paste-to-replace-selection.